# iPhone UIWebView - Can auto complete be turned off on a input text field?

Tags: iphone, autocomplete, input, uiwebview, autocorrect

I've searched high & low for an answer on this and I can't seem to find an answer or anybody else having the same issue.  Hope some one can assist?

I have a web page for signup which I'm viewing in an iPhone UIWebView.  A user is asking if we can stop capitalization on the first letter of the email address being entered.  I thought this didn't matter, but apparently it can for the local-part on some email systems (apparently it's only the domain that is only case insensitive).

It seems autocomplete is the culprit.
I've tried adding autocomplete="off" to the input element in the html, but iOS is obviously ignoring it:

[image]

Can auto-complete be turned off on a html input text field within a UIWebView?

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Seems like Apple have some documentation now:

> Although the UIWebView class does not support the UITextInputTraits
>   protocol directly, you can configure some keyboard attributes for text
>   input elements. For example, you can include autocorrect and
>   auto-capitalization attributes in the definition of an input element
>   to specify the keyboard’s behaviors, as shown in the following
>   example.

```
   <input type="text" size="30" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off">
```

> You can also control which type of keyboard
>   is displayed when a user touches a text field in a web page. To
>   display a telephone keypad, an email keyboard, or a URL keyboard, use
>   the tel, email, or url keywords for the type attribute on an input
>   element, respectively. To display a numeric keyboard, set the value of
>   the pattern attribute to "[0-9]*" or "\d*".
>
> These keywords and the pattern attribute are part of HTML 5, and are
>   available in iOS 3.1 and later. The following list shows how to
>   display each type of keyboard, including the standard keyboard.

Text: `<input type="text"></input>`

Telephone: `<input type="tel"></input>`

URL: `<input type="url"></input>`

Email: `<input type="email"></input>`

Zip code: `<input type="text" pattern="[0-9]*"></input>`

[http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html#Configuring the Keyboard for Web Views](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html#Configuring%20the%20Keyboard%20for%20Web%20Views)

Comment: As per the documentation gef points to, "autocapitalization" should actually be "autocapitalize" (that is not to say that Apple haven't changed it since the original answer).

Answer (score 29):

Add `autocorrect="off"` attribute to your input text field.