# How do I stop iOS text field autocomplete interfering with jQuery autocomplete?

Tags: jquery, ios, jquery-autocomplete

I'm using jQuery autocomplete on some of my text boxes which works perfectly... until you open the page on an iPad (or other iOS device) and the operating system's internal autocomplete takes over and ignores the `<input ... autocomplete="off" />` which ends up interfering with the jQuery autocomplete, as below:

[image: iOS Autocomplete Interference]

How do I make iOS not do that?

Comment: Add or change it to autocorrect="off"

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4000820/iphone-uiwebview-can-auto-complete-be-turned-off-on-a-input-text-field

Answer (score 2):

**PROBLEM SOLVED**

I had actually found the solution before I had posted the question, but thought it was a good point that somebody else might find useful and I'd post it anyway!

You need to add the following to your input elements:

```
<input type="text" ... autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" />
```